# Update not working, nothing is installing in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, dns

I am very much new to Linux. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
The problem is that I'm unable to install anything on it. Initially when I installed it, it was fine. But I was having some dependency problem with a package so I followed quite many tips to solve that issue. Since then I am getting errors (posted below) whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` command.

Can anyone help me solving this problem? I'm really in need. I couldn't install anything due to this issue. Software center has no install option when I select some software and when I try in terminal it always gives error:

```
E: Unable to locate package xyz

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
  Could not connect to 192.168.10.9:8080 (192.168.10.9), connection timed out
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                   
  Unable to connect to 192.168.10.9:8080:
.
.
.
.
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
.
.
.

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy (or something similar)? 192.168.10.9 indicates an address on your local connection.

Comment: Check contents of **/etc/hosts**. *This issue could also be caused by your ISP dropping (temporarily) DNS services (or changing hosts); OR your router/modem misdirecting DNS requests.*

Comment: @saiarcot895  no I'm not using any proxy...

Comment: How to solve the issue then? I'm clueless. I changed some file but I forgot which one was that.. Please help me I am not able to install anything at the moment